# Append data in excel file column wise in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am working to append data in csv file using fs.appendFileSync. I can easily append the data row wise but i can't find any way to append data in excel file column wise. For example, first fill column 'A' with data then column 'B' and so on. 
I am wondering if some one help me in this regard. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add new column to csv file using node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172921/how-to-add-new-column-to-csv-file-using-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

It will be very hard to do this task using fs.appendFileSync. Also, try not to use SYNC methods whenever possible.

For your problem I would recommend this npm module:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs

You can manipulate excel files using it. To add a rows and columns, just check docs.
For example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#rows

Comment: thanks a lot for your instant answer. I will check the module and will let you know if i need further help. Thanks

Comment: i have seen that it also add data in a array which is added as a row which somehow i able to do it but how column wise. Any way?