# Add column to csv file javascript:nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, fast-csv

I would like to add a column to my csv file that contains the same data for all rows

my csv file :

```
sugar, 150, stock
salt, 30, stock
milk, 30, stockout
```

my file after adding the row (expected result):

```
product, sugar, 150, stock
product, salt, 30, stock
prouct, milk, 30, stockout
```

I want to add the field "product" to each line, my code :

```
const writestream = fs.createWriteStream("file.csv", {
  flags: 'a'
});
writestream.write("," + "product");
```

This returns product at the end of the file, How can i fix it

can I use the fast-csv library to add this field?

Comment: please help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question was asked here: [How to add new column to csv file using node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172921/how-to-add-new-column-to-csv-file-using-node-js). Long story short, use csv-parser to convert the csv to json, add your field, then convert that json back into csv with json2csv.

```
var csv = require('csv-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var dataArray = [];

fs.createReadStream('your-original-csv-file.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', function (data) {
    data.newColumn = newColumnValue;
    dataArray.push(data);
  })
  .on('end', function(){
    var result = json2csv({ data: dataArray, fields:Object.keys(dataArray[0]) });
    fs.writeFileSync(fileName, result);
  });
```

This worked for me. The only problem is, I'm trying to loop that over multiple files I downloaded and renamed, it just doesn't save to all of them, only one.